# Simple UITextfield like the messages app

Tags: ios, resize, uitextfield, uikeyboard

can someone please point me in the direction of simple example where a textfield works similar to the messages app. I have looked at a lot of examples and they are all very complex and don't work that well. Surely UIKit supplies some simple functionality to replicate the textfield in the messages app.

To clarify, I am after logic to display a textfield that moves the entire view above the keyboard when pressed and resizes its self to display all entered text.

Thank in advance

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look on this [link](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController), search for the custom text input and use it as the model. It is fully documented.

Answer (score 0):

Use third party control like [DAKeyboardControl](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl)

`DAKeyboardControl` allows you to easily add keyboard awareness and scrolling dismissal (a receding keyboard ala `iMessages` app) to any `UIView`,`UIScrollView` or `UITableView` with only 1 line of code.

`DAKeyboardControl` automatically extends `UIView` and provides a block callback with the keyboard's current frame.

`DAKeyboardControl` now fully supports `orientation` changes, iPhone & iPad, and is even aware of keyboard undocking or splitting on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Register notification for keyboard show and hide notifications and then on the notification arrival just move you screen up and down for Keyboard UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification  respectively. you can do something like this to achieve keyboard show and hide. and for text field use text view instead.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];   
}


-(void)onKeyboardShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-100,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(void)onKeyboardHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```